# Is there a way to specificly pick out a sentence from a word document

Tags: python

so i have this simple code here it prints out the word doc, but I want to know if you can pick out a certain sentence like every sentence with a ? at the end example "where is the nearest Mcdonalds?"

```
import docx

def ReadingTextDoc(fileName):
    doc = docx.Document(fileName)

    completedText = []

    for paragraph in doc.paragraphs:
        completedText.append(paragraph.text)
    return '\n' .join(completedText)

print(ReadingTextDoc('Work.docx'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `list` with all of the sentences in the document:

```py
doc = [...]
for sentence in doc:
    if "?" in sentence:
        print(sentence)
```

If you have a paragraph, you can split it where there are dots:

```py
doc = [...]
for paragraph in doc:
    for sentence in paragraph.split("."):
        if "?" in sentence:
            print(sentence)
```